# Property 'path' does not exist on type 'StratifyOperator<unknown>'

Tags: typescript, typeerror

I am writing a React Component and i am using a template for a tree diagram of d3 (https://observablehq.com/@d3/tree). The template is written in js, i use ts.

I suppose i have to redefine the StratifyOperator<> type?
The error occurs in the fourth line before the end.

```
function Tree(
    data: {},
    {
      // data is either tabular (array of objects) or hierarchy (nested objects)
      path, // as an alternative to id and parentId, returns an array identifier, imputing internal nodes
      id = Array.isArray(data) ? (d: datatype) => d.id : null, // if tabular data, given a d in data, returns a unique identifier (string)
      parentId = Array.isArray(data) ? (d: datatype) => d.parentId : null, // if tabular data, given a node d, returns its parent’s identifier
      children, // if hierarchical data, given a d in data, returns its children
      tree = d3.tree, // layout algorithm (typically d3.tree or d3.cluster)
      sort, // how to sort nodes prior to layout (e.g., (a, b) => d3.descending(a.height, b.height))
      label, // given a node d, returns the display name
      title, // given a node d, returns its hover text
      link, // given a node d, its link (if any)
      linkTarget = "_blank", // the target attribute for links (if any)
      width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
      height, // outer height, in pixels
      r = 3, // radius of nodes
      padding = 1, // horizontal padding for first and last column
      fill = "#999", // fill for nodes
      fillOpacity, // fill opacity for nodes
      stroke = "#555", // stroke for links
      strokeWidth = 1.5, // stroke width for links
      strokeOpacity = 0.4, // stroke opacity for links
      strokeLinejoin, // stroke line join for links
      strokeLinecap, // stroke line cap for links
      halo = "#fff", // color of label halo
      haloWidth = 3, // padding around the labels
    }: any = {}
  ) {
    // If id and parentId options are specified, or the path option, use d3.stratify
    // to convert tabular data to a hierarchy; otherwise we assume that the data is
    // specified as an object {children} with nested objects (a.k.a. the “flare.json”
    // format), and use d3.hierarchy.
    const root =
      path != null
        ? d3.stratify().path(path)(data)
        : id != null || parentId != null
        ? d3.stratify().id(id).parentId(parentId)(data)
        : d3.hierarchy(data, children);
```